# Cannot assign an IAM role via PowerShell

Tags: azure, access-control, azure-powershell

The main problem is, that I can assign IAM role using the Azure portal, but got an error when trying the same via PowerShell.
This is the result of a portal action:
[image]

And I receive following error when I try to do the same via PowerShell:

```
> New-AzureRmRoleAssignment -ObjectId "d585d0b6-eb2b-4d7c-99b4-7c357219f78d" -RoleDefinitionName "Reader" -ResourceName "datalaketestmh" -ResourceType "Microsoft.DataLakeStore/accounts" -ResourceGroupName "My-Test-Resource-Group"
New-AzureRmRoleAssignment : Principal d585d0b6eb2b4d7c99b47c357219f78d does not exist in the directory 3596192b-fdf5-4e2c-a6fa-acb706c963d8.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzureRmRoleAssignment -ObjectId "d585d0b6-eb2b-4d7c-99b4-7c357219 ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureRmRoleAssignment], CloudException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Resources.NewAzureRoleAssignmentCommand
```

Any ideas where to look for the error?

Comment: Are you trying to assign the role to a user? If yes, please try using the `SignInName` parameter

Comment: that is not necessary, but probably easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this script to get user ID:

```
$a = Get-AzureRmADUser | ?{ $_.UserPrincipalName -eq 'username@xxxx.onmicrosoft.com' } | select id
$userid = $a.id.Guid
```

Then use `$userid` to assign the role:

```
New-AzureRmRoleAssignment -ObjectId $userid -RoleDefinitionName "Reader" -ResourceName "datalaketestmh" -ResourceType "Microsoft.DataLakeStore/accounts" -ResourceGroupName "My-Test-Resource-Group"
```

By the way, please check your Azure PowerShell version, my Azure powershell version is `5.1.1`, that script works for me:

```
PS C:\Users\jason> Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name Azure -Refresh


    Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\PowerShell\ServiceManagement


ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Script     5.1.1      Azure                               {Get-AzureAutomationCertificate, Get-AzureAutomationConnection, New-AzureAutomationConnection, Remove-AzureAutomationConnection...}
```

Also you can use **SignInName** inside of `ObjectId`, like this:

```
New-AzureRmRoleAssignment -SignInName john.doe@contoso.com -RoleDefinitionName Owner -Scope "/subscriptions/86f81fc3-b00f-48cd-8218-3879f51ff362/resourcegroups/rg1/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/site1"
```

More information about command `New-AzureRmRoleAssignment`, please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.resources/new-azurermroleassignment?view=azurermps-5.5.0).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Does this work for you? please let me know if you need more help:)

Comment: It worked, but this is even faster to search for user: `Get-AzureRmADUser -UserPrincipalName 'username@xxxx.onmicrosoft.com'`